# How show % near rows and columns in mode line?

Tags: mode-line

Emacs 26.1 
I use smart mode line: https://github.com/Malabarba/smart-mode-line

Here result:
[image]

Nice. It's work fine.

But I need to show **%** near rows and columns. 
Something like this:

**712:93 (17%)**

Is it possible?

Comment: `https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Mode-Line-Data.html`

Comment: I this tutorial I can't find how set %p near "line-number:column-number"

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**
I loaded up `smart-mode-line` myself, and took a more in depth look.

<strike>As a `smart-mode-line` user you'll need to edit your theme. Using the default [`smart-mode-line-powerline-theme.el`](https://github.com/Malabarba/smart-mode-line/blob/master/themes/smart-mode-line-powerline-theme.el) as an example, at [line 80](https://github.com/Malabarba/smart-mode-line/blob/master/themes/smart-mode-line-powerline-theme.el#L80) you'll find `sml/position-percentage`. Move this whole line up to line 63 ie: just below `sml/line-number`. This should get the effect you want.</strike>

Note that `smart-mode-line` uses the `Customize` facility. <strike>It may be easier (and saner) to make these changes there.</strike> Unfortunately you can't change the mode line format there. Only the faces.

To change the mode line format you'll want to study [Mode Line Format](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Mode-Line-Format.html) from the GNU Emacs Lisp Reference Manual. Pay special attention to the variables `mode-line-format` and `mode-line-position`. You'll need to move `mode-line-position` to where you want it with in `mode-line-format`. You can customize `mode-line-format` if you wish. You can reach its customize group by doing: <kbd>Meta</kbd>+x customize-group <kbd>Return</kbd> mode-line <kbd>Return</kbd>

It may just be easier to request that an easy way to reorder the mode line be added to `smart-line-mode`.

Comment: Change source not help. But how by Customize I can change percent position on smart-mode-line?

Comment: @Alexei please see my edits. What you want is doable, but probably not simple.

Comment: What do you mean "MOVE"? How I can move any settings? I think I can ONLY CHANGE any settings. Not move.

Comment: `mode-line-format` is an ordered list that represents the order of the items in your mode line. If you want to move an item on your mode line, you have to move that item's symbol in `mode-line-format`. In other words change `mode-line-format` so it's in a different order.

Comment: Yes. I change "mode-line-format" and now percent is exact after row:column.  ("%e" mode-line-front-space "%p" mode-line-mule-info mode-line-client mode-line-modified mode-line-remote mode-line-frame-identification mode-line-buffer-identification sml/pos-id-separator
 (vc-mode vc-mode)
 sml/pre-modes-separator mode-line-modes mode-line-misc-info mode-line-end-spaces). I remove default item "mode-line-front-space" and add item "%p". But the question is why , by default "mode-line-front-space" is a position percentage?